# How to generate object files in variant directory in scons

Tags: scons

I am using scons with python 2.7.1
my question is , i want to generate the object files in build directory.
but object files are creating in my source directory.

my code is:

```
env.Library('Liba', Glob(builddir + '/*.c'))
```

can you tell me how to generate the object file inbuild directory

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SCons terminology, what you are asking is called a variant directory, or simply `VariantDir`.  You have a few options for placing the targets in a VariantDir, as explained [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3361.html).

You could use the `VariantDir()` function which has the following syntax:

```
VariantDir(variant_dir, src_dir, [duplicate])
```

The `duplicate` argument is a `boolean`, which indicates if you want the source code copied to the variant dir or not.

Another way to use a VariantDir is if you have a hierarchy of SConstruct and SConscript script files, when calling the subsidiary SConscripts with the SConscript() function, one of the arguments is the `variant_dir`, as detailed here:

```
SConscript(dirs=subdirs, [name=script, exports, variant_dir, duplicate])
```

Notice the `SConscript()` function also has the `duplicate` argument.